# pdf not loading properly in Iframe (Flex) in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, apache-flex, html, iframe

I am loading a pdf in flex using  Iframe component. For that i have defined a div tag as follows in index.template.html.

```
<iframe name="_history" src="history.htm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="22" 
height="0"  ></iframe>
<!--This div is for the PDFiFrame-->
<div id="pdfFrame" style="position:absolute;left:0px; top: 0px; bottom :0px;right:   
0px;background-color:transparent;border:0px;visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

Now, my problem is it works fine in mozilla and chrome and pdf get loaded properly in assigned area i.e. Iframe. But in IE, it does not load properly in Iframe. It gets out of its boundries. Following is the code in mxml.

```
<mx:Canvas id = "myFrame" width="100%" height="100%" >  

<comps:IFrame id="iFr" visible="{availableFlag}" source="{srcUrl}" width="100%"  
height="100%" x="0" y="0" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

I think its because i am using absolute style in div tag. If i replace that with relative, PDF does not even load.

Can anybody tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

do you find any errors in IE? some javascript errors

this is [flex-iframe](https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe) site

Answer (score 0):

I spend month at least at different times with this IFrame component never works properly with one or the another browser! make sure if you want to use it to check and recheck & most likely with the next new update of a browser it is not working any longer - very surprised to hear that your FireFox is handling it - that has been the big problem not really the IE! regards aktell